# update UITableView when section is removed from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data

UITableView question :

I use Core Data and this delegate method to update my table view (of course with couple willChange and didChange)

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
 forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
```

Why the sections under my table view are not updated if I don't ask reloadData in the end of this delegate method ?!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without seeing your code.However, silly as it seems, you may have forgotten to set the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate. Check this in your code.